# Postman failed to access windows authentication based WebAPI running from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, windows-authentication

My postman got 401 Unauthorized when accessing https://localhost:7001/weatherforecast where the WebApi is running from Visual Studio 2019.
[image]

It is working fine if WebAPi is hosted in IIS or running the url from Chrome:
[image]

AspNetCore WebAPI configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddNegotiate();

            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: did you try giving domain and host ? try login from edge or ie it will prompt for ntlm authentication and see the domain name

Comment: @PDHide your comment helped me big time..i kept trying from postman and it was 401 always but from browser it worked! :)

Comment: Can we use postman on this web api with windows authentication?

Comment: Yes. Try NTLM Authentication in Authorization

Answer (score 0):

See the last comment above for the answer.  Set **Authorization** to **NTLM Authentication** within Postman, put in your credentials, and the call should work.